# Empty Array returned for Issue Links by Jira Cloud REST APIs

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

In Jira it's possible to link issues with relationships such as "blocked", "blocked by", etc.

While fetching one or multiple issues using Jira Cloud REST APIs (v3), within the object for each issue in the response, the IDs of the issue links should have been returned in the `issuelinks` array, as per the [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-links/).

But when I request such APIs (like `/rest/api/3/issue/<issue key>` or `/rest/api/3/search`) the response includes an **empty** array `"issuelinks": []`, **even for the issues for which linked issues are visible on the Jira cloud platform**.

I am using the API key generated from the cloud platform, and have verified that I have `Browse Projects` and `Link Issues` permissions. There is no `issue-level security` or `comment visibility restrictions` configured.

Would really appreciate some guidance here - **my goal is to fetch the list of issues and their linked issues via the API**, as it appears in the cloud platform. Thanks!

---

I tried requesting the get-specific-issue API with specific query parameter to fetch the Issue Links like `/rest/api/3/issue/<issue key>?fields=issuelinks` to try my luck - but it also returned the same empty array, as expected.

Since I was suspecting a permission-related issue, I requested APIs to verify permissions using the same API key like `/rest/api/3/mypermissions?permissions=BROWSE_PROJECTS` and `/rest/api/3/mypermissions?permissions=LINK_ISSUES` and both returned `true` - signifying that there is no permission issue.

Really no clue why the Issue Links are not returned.

Comment: I just tested it. I received issuelinks via API without problem. Can you show how issue look in Jira UI and what exactly is returned via API? My request:
`GET https://kb-test-1-new-url.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/SP-8` - No additional query params.